# How do I check the display styling of an element with Watin?

Tags: c#, watin

I'd like to do the following with watin. Maybe you guys know the best ways to go about doing this. I've been unable to find any thorough documentation on watin's power, I've even checked the homesite with little luck.

I'd like to...

1. Check the visibility/display value of a div.
2. Check the class name of an element.

eg:

```
Span this_span = Span(Find.ByText("Loading..."));

if (this_span.Visibility=="True")
{
}
```

and

```
if (this_span.Class.Value=="classname")
{
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Check the class name of an element.*

```
if (this_span.ClassName=="classname")
{

}
```

*Check the class name of an element.*

```
if (this_span.Style.GetAttributeValue("display")!="none")
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this_span.Style.Display != "none")
{
}
```